# HttpRequestException : failed to connect

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

HttpRequestException : failed to connect to baseurl.co.in/40.122.172.79 (port 443) from /192.168.0.102
(port 53040) after 120000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

This is an intermittent issue only sometimes it's coming in out test environment.
Whenever its failing the timeout always reported as 30 seconds.

Not sure is this failing on tcp layer on node server or webservice or any configuration issue on our azure devops hosting.

I am not able to reproduce this issue, Anyone help will be appreciated.

Comment: The "timeout always reported as 30 seconds" is what will be defined in the application making the http call (unless you configured settings this will be default) - the time the allocation waits for a response before it accepts its not getting one. If it is only happening on one environment I would suggest its a configuration issue (prob best to compare configs between test and your other environment/s). If its not config then the question could be asked, are you processing jobs or anything thats hogging IO? Have you exceeded your hosting plan usage?

Comment: Share the code how you are initializing HttpRequests, could be Socket Exhaustion